# Where is the error on the lines with variables there is a syntax error?

Tags: python-3.x, csv, syntax

```
import csv
from datetime import date
def calcAge(born):        # calculates age
    today = date.today()
    return today.year - born.year - ((today.month, today.day) < 
    (born.month, born.day)
byear = int(input("year of birth"))
fname = input("first name")
lname = input("last name")
dob = input("date of birth")
address = input("address")
age = calcAge(bornyear)
Data = [["FirstName", "SecondName", "DateOfBirth", "Address"],
[fname, lname, dob, age, byear, address]]

File = open("CustomerRecords2.csv", "a+")
with File:
writer = csv.writer(File)
writer.writerows(Data)

print ("done")
```

This code is to write a CSV file, but on the variable lines, there seems to be a syntax error that only appeared when I added the function.

Comment: I don't know what lines you mean exactly, but I see two problems: (1) there is a closing parenthesis missing after `((today.month, today.day) < (born.month, born.day)`, (2) the lines after `with File:` need to be indented. For (1) it would help to use a text editor that highlights matching parentheses.

Comment: (3) `bornyear` is not defined.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I'm a noob lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `age = calcAge(bornyear)` with `age = calcAge(byear)`. You have an undefined variable `bornyear`

Comment: Thank you, I'm a noob at programming

Comment: No problem. You have to start somewhere! If that solved your problem you can mark the answer as accepted. Thanks